# ssh tunneling ec2 -- Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, consul, ssh-tunnel

I have a hashicorp consul cluster that is in a private subnet on ec2. I want to access the consul web ui.

I added my key for ssh forwarding as:

`ssh-add -k <my_private_key>.pem`

I am able to use the following to log into my machines

`ssh -A ubuntu@<bastionIP>`

However when I try the following command for tunneling:

```
ssh -i <private_key>.pem -L 8500:10.0.31.163:8500 ec2-user@<bastion_public_IP>
```

I get the following error

`Permission denied (publickey)`

the `ssh -vvv` option output can be found here (IPs obfuscated):
https://paste.ubuntu.com/25405193/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu and Amazon Linux? I see you are using `ubuntu` user and `ec2-user`

Comment: I am doing what's specified in the consul guide [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/hashicorp/consul/latest/doc/hashicorp-consul-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf). All the instances are ubuntu instances.

Comment: If you can login with `ubuntu@`, then use that as your username when using tunelling, instead of `ec2-user`.

Comment: I tried that and it did log into the host 10.0.31.163 but when I try to access http://localhost:8500, I start getting these errors on the terminal - `channel 4: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`

Answer (score 0):

Remove any other ec2 private key that is already added in your system.

Then remove rm -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts

then try to connect with running ssh ec2-user@host

Comment: didn't do anything for me

Comment: can you please double check you are connecting with correct private keys. Also, you can follow this instruction http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html